# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "_enableIDFACollection" in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, google-analytics

I am new to stackoverflow and I searched for this problem on the internet and haven't found anything like the problem I have.

I am currently building a IOS app in xcode.

I made this project in unity with the google analytics plugin inside.

When trying to build in xcode I get this linking error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_enableIDFACollection", referenced from:
      _GAIHandler_enableIDFACollection_m7_14 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
      _GAIHandler__enableIDFACollection_m7_15 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
      _GoogleAnalyticsiOSV3_InitializeTracker_m7_94 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
      _GAIHandler_enableIDFACollection_m7_14 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
      _GAIHandler__enableIDFACollection_m7_15 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
      _GoogleAnalyticsiOSV3_InitializeTracker_m7_94 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _GAIHandler__enableIDFACollection_m7_15, _GAIHandler_enableIDFACollection_m7_14 )
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I had a error before while trying to link google analytics and I fixed that with the help of other stackoverflow threads.

The error I had before:

```
ld: library not found for -libGoogleAnalyticsServices
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This problem was easily solved by re-adding the lib file inside the build phases - Link Binary With Libraries.

Frameworks added:

1. CoreData.Framework
2. AdSupport.Framework
3. Libsqlite3.0.tbz
4. Libz.tbz
5. libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a

Compile sources added:

1. GAIhandler.m

I also checked the search paths inside the build settings and I did not find anything weird although I am not sure anymore.

EDIT

I tried adding libxml2.tbz

That did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you haven't included the files related to the library `GoogleIDFASupport`. Maybe this link can help you: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/optional-features

Comment: Thanks that did fix the error, but now i got another error - ld: library not found for -lGoogleAnalyticsServices
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation), which is weird since I already added libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a

Answer (score 0):

After several more xCode errors I went and put all the googleanalytics libraries inside my Unity project and rebuilded it.

That fixed the problem for me!

Hope that helps others who have the same problem.